# How to write C# CustomMarshaler to get a null terminated ANSI string from byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

How to write C# CustomMarshaler to get a null terminated ANSI string from byte array?

I have a lot of binary files that need to be parsed into structs. The best and clean way to do it that i see is to decorate the structs with MarshalAs attributes and use Marshal.PtrToStructure().

But i meet a problem. Default marshaling for strings does not work for me.

String in byte array are null-terminated, one byte per char (NOT pointer and not COM style).

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct DM
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(AnsiNullTerminatedString))]
    public string shader;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(AnsiNullTerminatedString))]
    public string texture;

    public uint flags;
    public float m_min_scale;
    public float m_max_scale;
    public uint num_vertices;
    public uint num_indices;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeParamIndex = 5)]
    public DMVertex[] vb;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U2, SizeParamIndex = 6)]
    public ushort[] ib;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct DMVertex
{
    public Vector3 point;
    public Vector2 texcoord;
}
```

This method i use to marshal byte array to struct:

```
public static T MarshalStruct<T>(byte[] data) where T : struct
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T temp = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return temp;
}
```

And that is my custom marshaler for string:
    public class AnsiNullTerminatedString : ICustomMarshaler
    {
        ...

```
    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pointerNativeData)
    {
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
        do
        {
            bytes.Add(Marshal.ReadByte(pointerNativeData, bytes.Count));
        } while (bytes[bytes.Count - 1] != 0);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
    }
}
```

But its crush.

Is there a way to write a correct custom marshaller for this kind of strings to solve this problem without using a manual marshalling or BinaryReader?

Comment: "But its crush" is not an appropriate problem description.  You cannot use SizeParamIndex for the arrays, must be SizeConst.  Go slower to debug the code, start with one field.

Comment: C language strings are bye[] arrays terminated with '\0';  So you want to located the '\0' and in GetStrings() only get the appropriate number of bytes.  You are probably getting a lot of garbage at the end of the string.